# Recover files from old Subversion backup

Tags: svn

I have a tar backup from an old subversion server which has long since died. All the source code which had been managed by this server is legacy code which will never be needed again ... except this one project.

The tar file is full of little directories like "conf", "dav", "db"...

Is there any way of extracting the final source code of a single project from this backup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have to extract the repository directory as a whole from the tar archive:

```
tar xvf oldSubversionServer.tar path/to/subversion/repository
```

Then you can browse the repository or create a working copy of your project with a `svn` client, using the `file:` access method.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about file access. 

I'm using a windows PC at the moment, so I used 7Zip to extract the repository I need, then installed TortoiseSVN, pointed it at the repository, and could access all the files.

Comment: could you use this file access over FTP (I know this probably doesn't make sense, but is it possible?)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new subversion server. Restore the backup into the new server. Copy the code you need out into your current subversion server.

Answer (score 1):

you could load the whole backup to the new server

```
tar xvf oldSubversionServer.tar | svnadmin load /var/svn/repos/temp
```

and then only dump that project

```
svnadmin dump /var/svn/repos/temp/project | gzip -9 > dump.gz
```

Load contents of a dump into the repository

```
gunzip -c dump.gz | svnadmin load /var/svn/repos/your_import_repo
```

this way you can keep you revisions for that project.