# Source / version control methodology

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, version-control

we are finally decided to switch from sourcesafe (the devil) to svn.
as we are a startup company we still have no idea of the best (not worst) way to save our code.
i have read about some ways others do that.
can any one give me a link to a good explanation for a source control methodology.
thank you.

update: using the software is nice and helpful. but we need to learn the methodology of how to save the code (branching trunk and tagging) how do you do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source Control - If, Why, How to start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064250/source-control-if-why-how-to-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between "backup" (as in "saving our code") and "versioning" (as in "saving a point in time of our code").
And there is a difference between saving it locally, or exporting that to a third-party provider (which, for private code might be problematic).

In other words, once you have begun to version you code, you will need to [backup regularly your SVN repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294893/svn-backup-repository) (and [test your backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653583/recover-files-from-old-subversion-backup) ;) ), but those are two different operations.

Comment: I wonder why you haven't recommended [git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064250/source-control-if-why-how-to-start/2064294#2064294) here...

Comment: @Tobias: because the OP mentions SVN in the question (at least in the tags)

Comment: fair enough. I just thought it might be worth mentioning the additional backup mechanism implicitly given by a distributed system (which shouldn't lead to carelessness though)

Comment: @Tobias: true, provided to not go too far ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576198/git-as-a-backup-and-version-control-system

Comment: good point and interesting read... what's your opinion of [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup) then?

Answer (score 2):

See the [answers here for this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064250/source-control-if-why-how-to-start) and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460022/preferred-version-control-methodology).

Also, a link to the [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I have used TortoiseSVN for multiple projects. It's free, easy to use and does everything SVN should do.

[TortoiseSVN's link](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

Here is a good tutorial to getting everything going using Tortoise.

[Tortoise Tutorial](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)

Enjoy and best of luck!